# Xcode: default Compile Sources for all new targets

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a C++ project in Xcode. The code is split over several files (hpp and cpp).

I need to add several targets with different main files. However every time I add a new target, I need to manually add all the other source files into Build Phases/Compile Sources.

Is there a way to specify within Xcode that a list of cpp files are to be added by default to the Compile Sources list whenever a new target is created?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a set of source files that are common between different programs (executable targets), why not create a *library* target for the common files, and make the executable targets link with that library?

Comment: Thanks, indeed what I am producing will eventually be a library. However at this stage I am still modifying the library source files and I am using different targets to test the library's usage. If I am not mistaken, if I now turn the cpp files into a library, when I make a change to the source files, I would need to recompile the library and then the target, for every modification I do. It is faster to simply add the source files once when the target is created. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you make changes to the library *interface*, the API, the public function signatures, then yes you need to rebuild all source files that use the changed API. But this will be automatic since the IDE should have all the dependencies set up correctly, so if a library header file is modified, the executable target source file using the modified header files will be recompiled, and the executable will be relinked with the updated library. The executable target will also be relinked automatically if the library itself is rebuilt, by modifying its internal files.

Comment: In short, it should all be automatic, and you don't really have to worry about these things.